# Acquiring Software via WebPi Through Web Proxy Requiring Authentication

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-platform-installer

I am behind a corporate firewall and the company I work for has VS 2012 Ultimate. I want to start developing for SharePoint 2013 using VS 2012. I found out later that the default installation does not include project templates for SP 2013, but requires to install "Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012" that can be found @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/apps/fp123627 .

This tool is installed through Web Platform installer. The MS WebPi has does not work where proxy authentication is required and throws an error.

Is there any offline installer for "Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012" ?

Comment: Do you have an MSDN license?

Comment: Oh, and BTW, have you asked the WebPI people if there's a way to configure it to permit proxy authentication?

Comment: no, dont have MSDN license. I have posted it on MSDN forum, lets see if anyone replies ...

Comment: If you are able to access the internet from elsewhere, then my answer here could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12351289/1035521

Answer (score 3):

Try creating or editing the existing application config file `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebPlatformInstaller.exe.config`.

[Create an assembly to provide proxy credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873292/enable-proxy-authentication-for-normal-windows-application) and specify the assembly in the [module element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903368%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <module type="ProxyCredProvider.DefProxy, ProxyCredProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5e3bf8f3a8a14cca" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an easier suggestion that worked for me. 
I suggest this be a **TEMPORARY** solution because your password is in CLEAR TEXT.

**1. Create two Windows environment variables:**

**NAME:** *HTTP_PROXY*
**VALUE:** *http://(YOUR USERNAME):(YOUR PASSWORD)@(IP ADDRESS OF THE PROXY SERVER):(PORT NUMBER OF PROXY)*
**EXAMPLE:** http://joe:password123@192.168.1.1:9090

**NAME:** *HTTPS_PROXY*
**VALUE:** *https://(YOUR USERNAME):(YOUR PASSWORD)@(IP ADDRESS OF THE PROXY SERVER):(PORT NUMBER OF PROXY)*
**EXAMPLE:** https://joe:password123@192.168.1.1:9090

**2. Sign out then back into the server**

**3. Try running Web Platform Installer again**

**HOW TO CREATE A WINDOWS ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE**

1. Go to Control Panel\System and Security\System
2. Select Advanced system settings
3. Select the Advanced tab
4. Click the Environment Variables.. button
5. The top section is for the currently signed in user. 
   Click the NEW button to add a new environment variable